# How to log Client IP Address and Machine Name in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, log4net

I am developing a Web Application in ASP.net, which requires login name and password.

I want to log IP Address and Machine Name of client, who are accessing this Web Application.

I am using log4net for logging.

I have tried this piece of code, but I am getting Server Machine HostName in log after deploying this web application using IIS-7 instead of Client Machine Name.

`Login Page Page_Load` Method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["Hostname"] = Dns.GetHostName();
}
```

Web.Config Changes:

```
 <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %property{Hostname} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
 </layout>
```

Its really huge project, So Please suggest me the way which requires minimum changes in Code to log the IP Address and Machine Name of Client.

Comment: Duplicate of [Get client's IP address and computer name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462188/get-clients-ip-address-and-computer-name)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you try using following?

```
Request.UserHostAddress

Request.UserHostName
```

Refer to following answer posted on a different thread

[Get client's IP address and computer name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462188/get-clients-ip-address-and-computer-name)

Answer (score 5):

Try
For Client Computer name..

```
string[] computer_name = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"]).HostName.Split(new Char[] { '.' });
  String ecname = System.Environment.MachineName;
            txtComputerName.Text = computer_name[0].ToString();
```

For Client IP address..

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

Check this also...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19286308/3156647

Answer (score 0):

```
Dns.GetHostEntry(log.IPAddress).HostName
```

For some reason the other answers didn't work on my shared hosting server. Go figure...

Answer (score 0):

For Client IP:

```java
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["**REMOTE_ADDR**"];
```

For Client Hostname:

```java
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["**REMOTE_HOST**"]).HostName;
```

Comment: Ensure that the server on which this application is hosted must have correct entry for the DNS Servers in TCP/IP configuration.